# iOS inheritance issue - failed to extend a class by subclassing

Tags: ios, xcode, oop

I've created a class Queue and a subclass QueueNumbers.

When i try to initialize the QueueNumbers everything works as expected.

```
QueueNumbers *queue = [[QueueNumbers alloc]init];
```

But when i try to call specific methods that are both:

- defined in the .h file
- implemented in the .m file

the queueNumbers instance fails to find them and tries to find them in Queue base class.

Queue.h

```
@interface Queue : NSObject{
    NSMutableArray *items;
    int maxSize;
}

-(id)init;
-(void)addItems:(id)_item;
```

QueueNumbers.h

```
@interface QueueNumbers : Queue
-(void)addNumbers:(int)_num;
@end
```

when i try to call addNumbers: of QueueNumbers it does not find the method.

any ideas?

Comment: Show us the method calls, the header file and the implementation of those methods you are talking about.

Comment: you're right. i'm new at the site. done.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the build? Can we see the code where you call addNumbers and what error messages you may be getting?

Comment: Just a sidenote: do not use variable names with underscore for method parameters (e.g. _num, _item). By convention variables prefixed with an underscore should be instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

The only reason it wouldn't is if the method signature doesn't match. And that includes the parameter. If it's not an `int` (like if you pass an `NSNumber` for example), then it won't work.

I can't see how you're calling the method, but chances are that's the issue.